# Last Col, Row and Range Copy Paste from multiple sheets to one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple sheets that pull data from ODBC, and it gets updated on a regular basis. Each of these sheet track different thing. For instance, "Check" tab tracks all the check transactions, "CreditCardCharge" tab tracks all the CC transactions...etc. I have created identical labels for all the sheets. e.g. Date, Ref Num, Account Name, Memo, Amount...etc I need all these sheet to be mapped to one master data dump sheet whenever I update the file.

This is the work flow:

- Clear all data in "LP_DataDump" tab starting from A2
- Copy "Check" tab data from A3 to Col J end row
- Paste copied data to "LP_DataDump" starting from A2
- Copy "CreditCardCharge" tab data from A3 to Col J end row
- Paste copied data to "LP_DataDump" starting from last empty row

I started with this below, but it's not working.

Can anyone advice?

```
Sub CopyCheckValue()

Dim Check As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set Check = Sheets("Check")
LastRow = Check.Cells(Check.Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row

Check.Range("A3:J" & LastRow).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("LP_DataDump").Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Comment: what is not working there ? your code look fine to me (for the first 3 points you mentioned in your workflow). Did you try to implement the last 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Does sheet "Check" contain only your data? Can I make a guess, is it due to the .End method skipping your data? If the last row in the "Check" sheet is your data, the .End method will find the end above it.

```
LastRow = Check.Cells(Check.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

To this:

```
LastRow = Check.Rows.Count
```

If your columns A and B have formulas that are empty while columns C to J do not have formulas but only data, I would recommend the code below, assuming there will always be data from C3 onwards and no empty cells in between C3 and the end of the table.

```
LastRow = Check.Cells(3, "C").End(xlDown).Row
```

If there are empty cells in between or formulas in other columns as well, use the LastRow as the first suggestion. Then use a loop to assign the values into the other sheet instead of copying and pasting the whole range.

```
PasteRow = 2
For RowCounter = 3 to LastRow
    If Check.Cells(RowCounter, "A") <> "" Then
        Check.Range(Cells(RowCounter, "A"),Cells(RowCounter, "J")).Copy
        Worksheets("LP_Datadump").Cells(PasteRow,"A").PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
        PasteRow = PasteRow+1
    End If
Next
```

If you have plenty of rows, I would recommend filtering before copying, that way you can avoid looping. Here's the code assuming you wish to filter it based on column A.

```
LastRow = Check.Rows.Count
Check.Range("A3:J" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:="<>"
Check.Range("A3:J" & LastRow).Copy
Worksheets("LP_Datadump"_.Cells(2, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
Check.Range("A3:J" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The bug is in fact coming from

LastRow = Check.Cells(Check.Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row

I am getting run time error "1004"

The "Check" tab contains only my data. The data is coming from QuickBook ODBC that I set up. I manipulated the data a bit and added column A and B. Column A label is account number and Column B is type. I have "Isblank" and "index" and "match" formula in these two column till cell "A65000". Will this affect my codes below?

Comment: Omg...I just replaced 

LastRow = Check.Cells(Check.Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row

to LastRow = Check.Rows.Count

It worked...many many thanks!

Comment: Although this works well, but now I am having trouble continuing with the rest of the sheets because I have blank cells with formula in column A and B. Whenever I copy and paste across from "Check" tab to "Datadump" tab, the blank cells with formula are also pasted in "Datadump" tab. Even I have made them copy paste special value, but it doesn't help to continue with another sheet because it return to last empty cell to A65000

Comment: Ok I've edited the answer to either check for the copy range using another method, or check whether the row is empty before copying. Note that the second method may be slow if there's a lot of rows as the loop makes it slow. If you have a lot of rows and wish to check, there's still a way to make it faster. I'll post up the answer in a bit, I'm on my daily commute! If the answer helped, it'll be great if you can give my answer and upvote! :)

Comment: Ok added the bit on filtering before copying. If that helps, let me know! :)